# Is there an outer measure with translation invariance properties expect Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was wondering if there is an outer measure on **R** which has the translation invariance properties of Lebesgue outer measure but it wasn't the Lebesgue outer measure.

(obviously, I don't mean something like multiplication of Lebesgue outer measure by a constant)

If the answer is negative, it means that we can define Lebesgue (outer) measure just by those properties.

Comment: Well, there is the counting measure. You can also just take a non-measurable automorphism of the reals and push the Lebesgue measure forward by it. But if you assume that intervals are measurable and have finite measure, then I think it is unique, by Caratheodory and the uniqueness of the Haar measure.